# Where can I find a worldwide General Aviation incident/accident ocurrence reports database?

Tags: general-aviation, accident-investigation

I enjoy reading reports about aviation incidents and accidents. There are often interesting technical details and I believe that this practice increases the safety of my flights.

To keep up to date I have set up a browser add-on which informs me daily about changes in the web-pages of several aviation safety agencies: NTSB, TSBC, IAC, BEA, AAIB, CIAIAC, BFU, SUB... This way I get to know about new occurrences and the publication of reports. However, depending on how each web page is structured, this method creates false positives, works only partially or doesn't work at all.

Is there any worldwide database or source informing about aviation occurrences and the publication of the corresponding reports?

I know about the Aviation Herald, but it only only deals with new occurrences on commercial aircraft. I'm especially interested in General Aviation and the publication of final reports.

Comment: There is not, as far as I know, a consolidated database for GA (or any) accident reports. The NTSB publishes reports of occurrences in other countries, but I think that is only when they are asked to participate in the investigation.

Answer (score 1):

No such official worldwide consolidated general aviation accident database exists. Most countries have their own, many smaller countries have none.

The closest you will find to a consolidated aircraft accident database is the one maintained at the Aviation Safety Network's [web site](https://aviation-safety.net/database/). However, this database does not qualify as an answer because it only covers airliner, military transport category aircraft and corporate jet aircraft safety occurrences since 1919, and then again only if the aircraft had 12 seats or more. Most other sites advertising such databases also have similar exclusions.

Comment: Please don't get into petty arguments in comments (now deleted). If you believe this to be an insufficient answer downvote it, leave a comment as to why (if you wish) and move on.

Comment: People who think absence of evidence is not evidence as absence should know that the burden of proof is on *them* to prove the statement. I'm done here. Thanks.